# Force HTML refresh at certain date ONCE

Tags: javascript, html, caching, browser

I am trying to create a forced refresh for all HTML pages + content on a site to occur once at a certain date. For CSS and JS content, this is relatively easy using version control and that's been done, my issue is with HTML pages. I would like to allow the content to be cached once the date has passed. Is this possible? I have tried to look at solutions but what I found would basically then force the user to reload all content again every time they visit the site after a certain date which is not what I am looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: Look for CronJob.

Comment: You could use a `setInterval` and `localeStorage` to track when last page refresh was performed.

Comment: @Keith basically checking if the user has loaded the latest version by timestamp and forcing a page reload() if the last access was before a certain date?